# Where did I err in finding the area of this region?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is the problem:

$$y=x^2-3x, y=3x+7$$

So the first thing I did was find the intersection points of the two functions:

$$x^2-3x=3x+7$$
$$x^2-6x-7=0$$
$$x=7, x=-1$$

So I figured these points were the bounds of my integral.  So I did this next:

$$\int_{-1}^{7}(3x+7)-(x^2-3x)dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^{7}(-x^2+6x+7)dx$$

From there I anti-differentiated and got:

$$\frac{-x^3}{3}+3x^2+7x$$

And finally I did $F(b)-F(a)$ and got 172.  But the system tells me this answer is incorrect and I don't know why.

Comment: The area crosses $x=0$.  Did you account for this negation in your final area?

Comment: @abiessu I believe so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did everything fine. At the substitution phase, there is a little error. It should be $\frac{256}{3}$.

When we substitute, we get
$$\left(-\frac{343}{3}+(3)(49)+49\right)-\left(\frac{1}{3}+3-7\right).$$

The part that doesn't have $3$ in the denominator is $200$. We subtract $\frac{344}{3}$, and get $\frac{600-344}{3}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer turned out to be $\frac{256}{3}$ I keep getting $\frac{403}{3}$

Comment: I used wolfram step-by-step to help me to see where I made a mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The unfortunate thing about slips in arithmetic is that sometimes they make people doubt the basic correctness of their work. In exam-grading, I have often given full marks to a well-described solution that has an insignificant error in arithmetic.

Comment: That's very encouraging, especially since I got all the actual calculus correct!

Answer (score 1):

Your antiderivative is correct; it seems like it's just an arithmetic error. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B7%7D%283x%2b7%29-%28x%5E2-3x%29dx) says that the answer is $256/3$.